# Are oopen cursors forward-only and read-only?

Tags: oracle, cursor, oracle-call-interface

Is a cursor created with oopen (from the Oracle 7.x OCI api) forward-only and read-only?

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cursors are both forward-only and read-only.

Comment: Thanks.  Any chance you know where the documentation is for the old OCI api?

Answer (score 1):

<s>A swift bout of Googling turned up [this link to the OCI 7 docs](http://www.gc.maricopa.edu/ic/bstewart/OracleServer733/DOC/api/doc/OCI73/toc.htm).  I don't know whether this publication is licit under Oracle's terms of use (even for educational sites).  On the other hand Oracle's OTN site only goes back as far as 8, so what choice do we have?</s>

As DCooke points out, OTN *does* have [the Oracle 7.3.4 docs](http://www.oracle.com/technology/documentation/oracle7.html).  I salute D's superior Google-fu.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technology/documentation/oracle7.html has the Ora 7.3.4 docs on Oracle's website.